Problema con la Configuración de NavController en MainActivity
Hola buenas, al intentar ejecutar mi Aplicación en Android Studio se me cierra al instante, mirando el logcat me señala el siguiente error(estoy programando con Kotlin)

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.roomapp/com.example.roomapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity com.example.roomapp.MainActivity@1a747ad does not have a NavController set on 2131230894

Soy nuevo en el desarrollo de aplicaciones para Android y la verdad que esto se me escapa bastante, agradecería que algun alma samaritana arrojara luz en este embrollo, os dejo abajo mis códigos
MainActivity.kt:
package com.example.roomapp
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setupActionBarWithNavController(findNavController(R.id.fragmentContainerView))
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.fragmentContainerView)
        return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}

activity_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/my_nav" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.RoomApp"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

Logcat:
(https://i.sstatic.net/VhMRBEth.png)

Hola. Si estás empezando con Android, te recomendaría que te vayas directamente a Jetpack Compose. Al implementarlo, ya no necesitarás de los XML para definir fragmentos o elementos de UI, pasando a un estilo de programación declarativo. Para más detalles, ver la página introductoria, ver el tutorial con varios ejemplos de lo que puedes hacer con Compose y sobre la navegación basada en Compose ver aquí.

@A.Cedano Vale muchas gracias, le echaré un ojo!

Vale, ya lo he podido arreglar, lo único que tenía que hacer es lo siguiente:
Eliminar de mi código en MainActivity.kt:
setupActionBarWithNavController(findNavController(R.id.fragmentContainerView))

Y añadir en la segunda función que hay en el archivo:
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerView) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)

